# How to connect node.js with Windows server with SQL Server using Windows authentication?

Tags: node.js, sql-server, odbc

I've been trying to connect my nodejs API to SQL Server using Windows authentication. I got it to work a while back using another connection method, via user login, but I want to use Windows authentication.

Here's my Javascript code:

```
const sql = require('mssql/msnodesqlv8');
const sqlConfig = {
    server: 'LAPTOP-MFFHR5E2',
    database: 'universaltest1',
    driver: "msnodesqlv8",
    options: {
        trustedConnection: true,
        enableArithAbort: true,
        encrypt:false,
    }
};

//test:
async function testQuery() {
    try {
        await sql.connect(sqlConfig);
        const result = await sql.query`SELECT 1 AS number`;
        console.log(result);
        // Successfully connected and queried
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('Error:', err);
    } finally {
        await sql.close();
    }
}

testQuery();
```

I get this error:

> Error: ConnectionError: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
>
> at PrivateConnection.callback2 (C:\Users\user\photo-gallery\loginAPI\node_modules\mssql\lib\msnodesqlv8\connection-pool.js:46:17)
> at Immediate. (C:\Users\user\photo-gallery\loginAPI\node_modules\msnodesqlv8\lib\connection.js:41:14)
> at process.processImmediate (node:internal/timers:478:21) {
>
> code: undefined,
> originalError: [Error: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified] {
> sqlstate: 'IM002',
> code: 0,
> severity: 0,
> serverName: '',
> procName: '',
> lineNumber: 0
> }

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified your DSN name in connectionString in sqlConfig={....}
Specify like below

```
const sqlConfig = {
//rest of code
...
connectionString: 'DSN=YourDSNName;'
}
```

Let me know if this worked or not.

Comment: when i add that field to my JavaScript object, i get a new error that basically says 
>Error: ConnectionError: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name too long

So i think it's redundant in that case :/

When i try to use ONLY connection string without all the other configuration  get:

>Error: ConnectionError: Login failed for user ''.